# Why doesn't this NIntegrate work?

Tags: numerical-integration

I need the following integral to use it later on for a nested integral:

```
i3[z1_?NumericQ, z2_?NumericQ] := i3[z1, z2] = NIntegrate[1/(1+(1+(x1-
x2)^2)^(1/3)), {x1, 0, z1}, {x2, 0, z2}, Method -> "MonteCarlo" ​];
```

Unfortunately, if I run `i3[1,1]`, it does not return me any numerical value? If I remove `Method -> "MonteCarlo"` ​, then things work. However, I need this method for the purpose of computation speed. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Why the `i3[z1, z2] =` part?

Comment: @Feyre it's a [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) for function.

Comment: Did you copy this code from a comment on this website?  There are problems with comments recently that insert invisible characters that break the code.  http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1955/copy-to-and-from-comment ( @m0nhawk )

Comment: I did not copy this code from any website. Unfortunately, I did not realise that there was a space after "MonteCarlo", which seems to be the main trouble.

Comment: No, the space is not the problem.  The problem is the invisible *zero-width space* (Unicode `0x200b`) character *after* the standard space.  Have you any idea how it got there?

Comment: No idea. I typed everything myself.

Comment: Does it give an error message?

Comment: Nope. It returns the code itself as an output.

Answer (score 3):

You have some issue with the encoding.

If you copy your part into some HEX editor you'll get:

```
п»ї"MonteCarlo" вЂ‹];
```

While the correct is:

```
п»ї"MonteCarlo" ];
```

The `п»ї` part is a `EF BB BF`, just a UTF-8 marker.

And the problem is: `вЂ‹`, it's a "ZERO WIDTH SPACE" with code `E2 80 8B`. Removing that space will result in a correct execution.

This may be some copy-paste protection from a third-party sites.

Comment: Actually it appears to just be a typo, `i3[z1_?NumericQ, z2_?NumericQ] := 
  i3[z1, z2] = 
   NIntegrate[
    1/(1 + (1 + (x1 - x2)^2)^(1/3)), {x1, 0, z1}, {x2, 0, z2}, 
    Method -> "MonteCarlo" ];` work fine, the rules are differet, this gives `0.489461` as result.

Comment: I used a clear kernel, works fine for me.